# Execute A Function from Functions.php in Form

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a form which displays a certain piece of user_meta data and I want to be able to update this usermeta on form submit.

This is what I have at the moment;

```
function my_form_funnction() {
global $current_user;

$vat_no = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'vat_number', true );

?>
<form name="setPrices" action="" method="POST">

<label for="lowPrice">Vat Number: </label>
<input type="text" id="vat_number" name="vat_number" value="<?php echo $vat_no ?>" />


 <button type="submit">Save</button>
 </form>

 <?php update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'vat_number',      esc_attr($_POST['vat_number']) );
}
```

But the thing is the php that updates the user meta does so when the page loads, I only want it to do it when the user pressess save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax to update information on a page without refreshing it. Try jQuery! It is a realy simple way to use Ajax. For example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="javascript:la()">Save or do smth</button>
<div id="a">Here will be included the loadable thing</div>
<script>
function la(){
$("#a").load("/functions.php?func=my_form_function");
}
</script>
```

And in functions.php you may set:

```
if(isset($_GET["func"]){
if($_GET["func"] == "my_form_function"){
my_form_funnction();
}
```

}

Comment: when i add that exact code to functions.php it gives error? any ideas